# Is it possible to arrange the books alphabetically in your Journal?

Tags: diablo-iii

It's nice of Blizzard to keep a record of whatever books I have collected so far, but for an organized soul like me, it just kills me to not be able to arrange the books in an order I'd like. The only order available is the default order, which is from the most recent to the oldest. Is it possible at all to arrange them or am I stuck with this horrendous order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rearrange them in a a limited fashion but not alphabetically or in a user defined order.

This Hellish or Infernal order is the order of the day.